# How to update marker on google map api 2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have to show multiple marker on google map api 2. Marker will use a layout which have an ImageView which will get image from webService. And I have to show image in Circular way. I tried a lot but I didnt find any good Solution.

Comment: Have you referred the google map sdk demo for ploating the multiple markers on Map ?